Testing the difference between two Root Mean Square Error values for statistical significance
I would like to compare the predictive power of 2 models. The models are meant to model count data and respective probabilities. I am using two metrics as means of comparison:

Root Mean Square Error
Another metric based on a "score function" related to mean square  (like Brier score)

I have a dataset with actual observed values, and the predicted values given by both models  for this dataset. I have no further information about the models (i.e. the number of predictors or the specific type of predictive models used).
Question: what significance test is possible to use to determine if the difference between computed values of each of the metrics for the two models is significant? I am in particular interested in RMSE. And how to apply the test?

This won’t help you right now, but if you’re generally interested in comparing model performance, Benavoli’s “Time for a Change” article is worth a read. $//$ Without access to any model information, just the residuals (“errors”), I find it hard to believe that anything besides a computational approach is viable: permutation testing or bootstrap.

The "time series aspect" of the proposed duplicate is not a hindrance: look up the Diebold-Mariano test. @Dave: thank you for that reference, will read it... though the forecasting community has indeed been moving towards testing differences in accuracy for a few years now, typically using a Multiple Comparisons to the Best (MCB) test. I would say this makes sense, given how often different forecasting methods differ only slightly in accuracy.

@StephanKolassa The metric they consider throughout the paper is classification accuracy. You’ll love it! (I do think their work makes sense for other metrics like log loss or square loss, however.)

@Dave: ah, thank you for the warning, I will then read it on a Good Day ;-)
